# Installing Geant4 alongside GEANT3: Question for Unix and Linux meta?

Tags: discussion, support, scope, asking-questions

I intend to ask the following question:

**Can I install Geant4 alongside GEANT-3 on my Ubuntu 15.04 (Vivid Vervet)? I have already installed GEANT-3. How can I install Geant4 without making any problems?**

Can I ask the question on Unix and Linux as suggested by an [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298563/3623705) at Stack Overflow meta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I ask the question on Unix and Linux as suggested by an answer at Stack Overflow meta?

Yes.  Factors such as how `$PATH` is set on *nix systems including Ubuntu might be relevant, so it is entirely appropriate here.

Comment: Hey, help me out here http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/214640/84855 . I took every precaution to avoid asking the wrong question at the wrong place. But still I got the downvotes. Where did things go wrong?

Comment: People with >= 125 rep but < 250 rep can downvote but not close vote and are less likely to understand the purpose of various mechanisms, so may downvote because they *think* something is off-topic, I guess.   Why whatever happened there happened so fast is a bit baffling, there are plenty of worse questions on a regular basis that get no downvotes at all even after hours and days.